# Trophy/achievement woes in Tomb Raider

Tags: achievements, tomb-raider-2013

I'm playing Tomb Raider on PS3,
now there are two trophies I have a problem with:

1. **Adventurer** - *Complete a match in all multiplayer modes.*

   I have completed a match in all 4 modes in *Casual*. Do I need to also complete them in *Ranked* for this trophy to pop?
2. **On My Way Up** - *Reach level 10 in multiplayer.*

   I have *definitely* reached Level 10 in multiplayer, but this trophy didn't pop-up.

Are these trophies/achievements glitched?

Comment: I can even get enough players in a ranked lobby for a match. Good Luck!

Comment: You're right, multiplayer in this game is a huge pain in the *ss.
And I was thinking of this being the first game I plat..

Comment: Just re-read that comment, i meant *can't. oops.

Comment: Don't worry, I got that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the **Adventurer** Trophy:

> There are four multiplayer modes (Rescue, Team Deathmatch, Cry for
>   Help, Free-For-All) and you have to complete a match in each one. **Note
>   that you have to finish a match and not just a round but if you join a
>   game that is already in session, that will count. You can also choose
>   either Ranked or Casual, it won’t matter.**
>
> **Note: You can check your progress for this trophy and all other
>   multiplayer related trophies by choosing Feats & Setbacks from MP main
>   menu. They will be under Trials section.**

That being said, you can check to see if each of the trophies are glitched if they say they are completed.

For the **On My Way up Trophy** and the **True Commitment Trophy**:

From what I have read, there haven't been many outcries about any issue(s) with this trophy, [not saying there isn't a local issue with your system] but be sure to check your status of earning this trophy as mentioned before.

> You need 1,771,100 experience to reach level 60. Depending on your
>   skill level or whether you will boost it or not, it will take at least
>   15 to 20 hours to reach level 60. Also you won't unlock the trophy
>   until the end of your current round/match.

[Source](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/tomb-raider/190879-tomb-raider-trophy-guide-road-map.html) & [boosting thread](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/tomb-raider/190616-trophy-boosting-thread-read-first-post.html) if interested in the Platinum.

*Also note that you need to Prestige at least 3 times for the Platinum to pop.*

Comment: All of guides that I have looked at report zero glitched trophies.  Hope this helps